# Supr, and 3 arrows keys not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard

Well, my arrows (up, left, down) and my supr(or del) key are not working.. 
I tried with 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
with a few different keybords, and changing System Settings about the keyboard but nothing happens. I keep getting this image with and X every time I use these keys(in chrome, firefox, terminal, etc).
The arrows are working well with "Fn". And they were working yesterday as arrows.

Comment: What's the result of pressing `QWERTY` in your keyboard?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the image? (You can post it somewhere online like imgur.com or postimage.org and add a link in your question, if you're unable to include it in your question directly.) Right now it would be hard to answer this and it might be closed as unclear, but even after it's closed, if you edit it, that will get it reconsidered for reopening.

Answer (score -1):

I'll suggest you not to randomly select the keyboard model. Select the one that match to your machine.
e.g. I am using Acer Aspire E1-410, so I have to select Acer Laptop as the keyboard model.